# How to create a multi-tenant database with shared table structures?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, multi-tenant

Our software currently runs on MySQL. The data of all tenants is stored in the same schema. Since we are using Ruby on Rails we can easily determine which data belongs to which tenant. However there are some companies of course who fear that their data might be compromised, so we are evaluating other solutions.

So far I have seen three options:

- Multi-Database (each tenant gets its own - nearly the same as 1 server per customer)
- Multi-Schema (not available in MySQL, each tenant gets its own schema in a shared database)
- Shared Schema (our current approach, maybe with additional identifying record on each column)

Multi-Schema is my favourite (considering costs). However creating a new account and doing migrations seems to be quite painful, because I would have to iterate over all schemas and change their tables/columns/definitions.

**Q:** Multi-Schema seems to be designed to have slightly different tables for each tenant - I don't want this. Is there any RDBMS which allows me to use a multi-schema multi-tenant solution, where the table structure is shared between all tenants?

P.S. By multi I mean something like ultra-multi (10.000+ tenants).

Comment: "Multi-Schema seems to be designed to have slightly different tables for each tenant"  So?  What's wrong with multi-schema and all the same tables?   Are you saying you don't want to recreate identical table structures in all schema?  Or are you saying that you can't create identical structures in all schema?

Comment: +1 for good/interesting question

Comment: @S.Lott I expect 10.000+ tenants with 100+ signups a day. Having millions of entries in a single table-definition (definition = shared, data = isolated) makes me feel better than having thousands of entries in thousands of table-definitions. Since not many people are doing it that way I'm not so confident with multi-schema.

Comment: @Marcel: That excludes multi-database for sure. How much data are you expecting to store for each tenant? Kilobytes, Megabytes, or Gigabytes of data?

Comment: @Daniel: As stated blow to your reponse, Number = 10k, Storage = 50mb, Concurrent End-Users = 2 per tenant, Addons = 0. So the current situation having a shared approach seems to be the most reasonable.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, multi-database is excluded based on those figures. I've updated my answer to reflect that, but keeping it more for history. Shared approach definitely does seem the most reasonable approach.

Comment: from [dynjo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2022554/dynjo) in an answer: "[Great article](http://ryanbigg.com/2013/01/multitenancy-with-rails/) from Ryan Bigg on the exact subject"

Comment: You also need to consider how are you going to scale / replicate / backup and stuff. I think the best approach for most cases is to have multi-tenant tables where every table has an account_id (customer_id, tenant_id, call it what you want) identifying the actual tenant. My 2c

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> However there are some companies of
>   course who fear that their data might
>   be compromised, so we are evaluating
>   other solutions.

This is unfortunate, as customers sometimes suffer from a misconception that only physical isolation can offer enough security.

There is an interesting MSDN article, titled [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx), which you may want to check. This is how the authors addressed the misconception towards the shared approach:

> A common misconception holds that
>   only physical isolation can provide an
>   appropriate level of security. In
>   fact, data stored using a shared
>   approach can also provide strong data
>   safety, but requires the use of more
>   sophisticated design patterns.

As for technical and business considerations, the article makes a brief analysis on where a certain approach might be more appropriate than another:

> The number, nature, and needs of the
>   tenants you expect to serve all affect
>   your data architecture decision in
>   different ways. Some of the following
>   questions may bias you toward a more
>   isolated approach, while others may
>   bias you toward a more shared
>   approach.
>
> - How many prospective tenants do you expect to target? You may be nowhere
>     near being able to estimate
>     prospective use with authority, but
>     think in terms of orders of magnitude:
>     are you building an application for
>     hundreds of tenants? Thousands? Tens
>     of thousands? More? The larger you
>     expect your tenant base to be, the
>     more likely you will want to consider
>     a more shared approach.
> - How much storage space do you expect the average tenant's data to occupy?
>     If you expect some or all tenants to
>     store very large amounts of data, the
>     separate-database approach is probably
>     best. (Indeed, data storage
>     requirements may force you to adopt a
>     separate-database model anyway. If so,
>     it will be much easier to design the
>     application that way from the
>     beginning than to move to a
>     separate-database approach later on.)
> - How many concurrent end users do you expect the average tenant to support?
>     The larger the number, the more
>     appropriate a more isolated approach
>     will be to meet end-user requirements.
> - Do you expect to offer any per-tenant value-added services, such
>     as per-tenant backup and restore
>     capability? Such services are easier
>     to offer through a more isolated
>     approach.

---

**UPDATE:** Further to update about the expected number of tenants.

That expected number of tenants (10k) should exclude the multi-database approach, for most, if not all scenarios. I don't think you'll fancy the idea of maintaining 10,000 database instances, and having to create hundreds of new ones every day.

From that parameter alone, it looks like the shared-database, single-schema approach is the most suitable. The fact that you'll be storing just about 50Mb per tenant, and that there will be no per-tenant add-ons, makes this approach even more appropriate.

The MSDN article cited above mentions three security patterns that tackle security considerations for the shared-database approach:

- [Trusted Database Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tdc)
- [Tenant View Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tvf)
- [Tenant Data Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tde)

When you are confident with your application's data safety measures, you would be able to offer your clients a [Service Level Agrement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_level_agreement) that provides strong data safety guarantees. In your SLA, apart from the guarantees, you could also describe the measures that you would be taking to ensure that data is not compromised.

**UPDATE 2:** Apparently the Microsoft guys moved / made a new article regarding this subject, the original link is gone and this is the new one: [Multi-tenant SaaS database tenancy patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns) (kudos to Shai Kerer)

Comment: Oh, I scanned that article yesterday and skipped that misconception-part. Need to read it again.

Comment: @Marcel: However, apart from what the customers' perception of security is, I believe your decision on which multi-tenant approach to take should be based on factors like those 4 points I quoted from the MSDN article: 1. Expected number of tenants. - 2. Expected storage requirement for each tenant. - 3. Expected number of concurrent end-users. - 4. Expected per-tenant addons.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that section. Number = 10k, Storage = 50mb, Concurrent End-Users = 2 per tenant, Addons = 0. So the current situation having a shared approach seems to be the most reasonable. I think I'll do some calls next week to find out what customers really need / expect. Germany and data/IT-security is a really tough story.

Comment: Just for the users reading this from now on, the mentioned article doesn't exist anymore, someone made a copy, perhaps?

Comment: @guillesalazar I'm not sure its the same one but I guess it is - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns
(@DanielVassallo if it is the same, perhaps consider updating the link in your answer :-) )

Comment: @DanielVassallo
in my case, I'm going with a single DB server intance, but facing a problem of max connections limit. Can you have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880495/create-a-connection-pool-for-many-dbs-on-the-same-db-server-spring-boot

Answer (score 24):

Below is a link to a white-paper on Salesforce.com about how they implement multi-tenancy:

http://www.developerforce.com/media/ForcedotcomBookLibrary/Force.com_Multitenancy_WP_101508.pdf

They have 1 huge table w/ 500 string columns (Value0, Value1, ... Value500).  Dates and Numbers are stored as strings in a format such that they can be converted to their native types at the database level.  There are meta data tables that define the shape of the data model which can be unique per tenant.  There are additional tables for indexing, relationships, unique values etc.

Why the hassle?

Each tenant can customize their own data schema at run-time without having to make changes at the database level (alter table etc).  This is definitely the hard way to do something like this but is very flexible.

Answer (score 22):

My experience (albeit SQL Server) is that multi-database is the way to go, where each client has their own database. So although I have no mySQL or Ruby On Rails experience, I'm hoping my input might add some value.

The reasons why include :

1. data security/disaster recovery. Each companies data is stored entirely separately from others giving reduced risk of data being compromised (thinking things like if you introduce a code bug that means something mistakenly looks at other client data when it shouldn't), minimizes potential loss to one client if one particular database gets corrupted etc. The perceived security benefits to the client are even greater (added bonus side effect!)
2. scalability. Essentially you'd be partitioning your data out to enable greater scalability - e.g.  databases can be put on to different disks, you could bring multiple database servers online and move databases around easier to spread the load.
3. performance tuning. Suppose you have one very large client and one very small. Usage patterns, data volumes etc. can vary wildly. You can tune/optimise easier for each client should you need to.

I hope this does offer some useful input! There are more reasons, but my mind went blank. If it kicks back in, I'll update :)

**EDIT:**
Since I posted this answer, it's now clear that we're talking 10,000+ tenants. My experience is in hundreds of large scale databases - I don't think 10,000 separate databases is going to be too manageable for your scenario, so I'm now not favouring the multi-db approach for your scenario. Especially as it's now clear you're talking small data volumes for each tenant!

Keeping my answer here as anyway as it may have some use for other people in a similar boat (with fewer tenants)

Comment: Yeah, sorry that I didn't clarify that earlier. Still +1. ;)

Comment: talking about data security, will you say that each database should be placed on separated servers / VMs ? or having all the databases on a single / clustered server with different sql users is secure enough?

Comment: @Shay - No, shouldn't need to place them on separate servers - imagine you have 100s, that is a lot of server instances/licenses you'd need for a start. See Daniel's answer further up, there's some good links in there.

Comment: I would argue back that even if multi-DB means 10,000 separate databases and turn increases the maintenance cost significantly, you can still tame this beast using automation scripts over your cloud infrastructure such that everything becomes programmatically managed, requiring little to no human effort at all

Answer (score 13):

As you mention the one database per tenant is an option and does have some larger trade-offs with it. It can work well at smaller scale such as a single digit or low 10's of tenants, but beyond that it becomes harder to manage. Both just the migrations but also just in keeping the databases up and running.

The per schema model isn't only useful for unique schemas for each, though still running migrations across all tenants becomes difficult and at 1000's of schemas Postgres can start to have troubles.

A more scalable approach is absolutely having tenants randomly distributed, stored in the same database, but across different logical shards (or [tables](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/11/30/sharding-your-database/)). Depending on your language there are a number of libraries that can help with this. If you're using Rails there is a library to enfore the tenancy [`acts_as_tenant`](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant), it helps ensure your tenant queries only pull back that data. There's also a gem [`apartment`](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) - though it uses the schema model it does help with the migrations across all schemas. If you're using Django there's a number but one of the more popular ones seems to be across [schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). All of these help more at the application level. If you're looking for something more at the database level directly, [Citus](https://www.citusdata.com) focuses on making this type of sharding for [multi-tenancy](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/08/10/sharding-for-a-multi-tenant-app-with-postgres/) work more out of the box with Postgres.