# multi tenant database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to create a multi tenant database for codeigniter project. if one tenant sign up on my project then I need to create an individual database with same tables look likes my original database. 
Let me know how to start and access with multi tenant concepts.

Comment: your question is not clear what you want create a new database with same host or different host please clear your question.

Comment: Want to create a new multi tenant database for the same host

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, consider editing your question to conform to the standards listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - more concise information would go far in helping us understand your needs.

Comment: did you trying to create the multi tenant database in phpmyadmin

Comment: yes i tried using phpmyadmin.

Comment: reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213006/how-to-create-a-multi-tenant-database-with-shared-table-structures

Comment: ya i need to implement this in codeigniter.